# Trying to restore model, but tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path) raises error

Tags: tensorflow

I downloaded pretrained mobilenetV2 models from [tensorflow models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/README.md),and try to restore the graph,but got unexpected error.

Codes to reproduce the error is pretty concise:

```
import tensorflow as tf
meta_path = 'path/to/mobilenet_v2_0.35_224/mobilenet_v2_0.35_224.ckpt.meta'
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
```

then the last line raises error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/CVAR/study/codes/languages/python/pycharm/learn_tensorflow/train_mobileNet_v2/test_of_functions/saver_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1960, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 744, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 391, in import_graph_def
    _RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 158, in _RemoveDefaultAttrs
    op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: 'InfeedEnqueueTuple'
```

My system information is :

```
ubuntu 16.04
python 3.5
tensorflow-gpu 1.9
```

Any idea?

Comment: append `saver.restore(sess, 'path/to/mobilenet_v2_0.35_224/mobilenet_v2_0.35_224.ckpt')` after `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)`

Comment: @BugKiller Thanks for your comment. However, actually I always do append the 'saver.restore(...)' function, which raises the same error. The codes above is put for conciseness, therefore I didn't put all codes.

Comment: my bad. find a [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/mobilenet_example.ipynb)

Comment: @BugKiller well, thank you again.I knew the demo codes there, but couldn't figure out why the codes here raise error,and come here for an answer~~

Comment: @BugKiller that example doesn't load the meta graph file. It builds the graph again and then loads the variables from the checkpoint, which defeats the purpose of meta graphs - Tensorflow devs really need to stop using this approach, where checkpoints are unusable if the code changes.

I got the same error trying to load the meta file. You could try filing a Github issue, but the research/ models aren't really supported. Sorry I couldn't offer any real help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently also met such a problem. It seems like the reason is that the TensorFlow version you use to train the model is different from the version you use to read the graph description proto. What you need to do is to reinstall the TensorFlow to your training version. Otherwise, retraining the model would work.

FYI, the TensorFlow version I used to train is 1.12.0, by contrast, the version I use to load the graph is 1.13.1. Reinstallation solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ops not defined.  `from conv_blocks import *` will fix this bug but I got another problem "ValueError: NodeDef expected inputs 'float, int32' do not match 1 inputs specified;".  Still debugging, but hope this tip solves your problem.